# layout is not moving up when keyboard is shown

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a `NestedScrollView` in my activity with about 7-8 edit texts and I need them move up when keyboard is shown. I'm doing this but it's not working

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context="com.amir_p.cafino.LoginActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grayTransparent" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/signup_layout"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/register_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                android:hint="نام و نام خانوادگی"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            [...]
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `android:fillViewport="true"` for your scrollview

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:visibility="visible">
```

and in manifest add:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

you can programetically turn off fillscreen mode:

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

**Fullscreen mode does not resize.**

or u can use different theme: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar`

Comment: Also if u are using a Fullscreen theme for your activity ...u need to change it

Comment: ok that was because of my fullscreen theme. what can I do for that?